# Django multi-tenant

Tags: django, multi-tenant

I have a very simple project that contains an app with the following models.py:

```
class UserAccount:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    additional = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Project:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Record:
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want different teams to be able to use this app. However, I want the tables to be separated in some way (don't want all the account, projects and records in the same table).

One solution is to duplicate this app for each team, which is bad.
Another is to use something like https://github.com/bcarneiro/django-tenant-schemas, but I want to avoid multiple subdomains.

The way I'd like to manage urls is:

- mysite.com/teamA/
- mysite.com/teamB/
- mysite.com/admin/teamA/
- mysite.com/admin/teamB/

I read a lot of articles on the web about muti-tenancy in Django but did not found one solution that fit my needs:

- 1 DB but not all tenant data in the same tables
- no use of sites or sub-domains but instead: mysite.com/tenant1/, mysite.com/tenant2/,

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be too difficult. You'll have to write your own middleware and put it in your settings.py. Copy and paste this file and modify it to use a different part of your url than the subdomain here:

https://github.com/bcarneiro/django-tenant-schemas/blob/master/tenant_schemas/middleware.py